# How can I maintain the position of a widget in a SingleChildScrollView after setState updates the ui

Tags: flutter

I am using **SingleChildScrollView** with a **Card** widget as the child. The problem is each time I call **setState** , the position of the widget is reset to the initial position, in essence, the scroll position is reset whenever I call **setState**.

How can I fix this issue because the user would have to scroll down to the position before **setState** was called.

[***Here is a detailed UPDATE to the original concise code***]

```dart
    class SearchPage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _SearchPageState();
    }
    
    class _SearchPageState extends State<SearchPage> {
      Map<String, dynamic> _arguments;
      List<List<List<Map<String, bool>>>> _voucherReferenceTracker;
      GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey;
    
      Map<String, dynamic> _selectedOffer;
      List<List<List<Map<String, bool>>>> _voucherReferenceTracker;
      var _selectedVouchers;
      var _viewIndex=0;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        _arguments = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
        _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
        return WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: _onWillPop,
            child: Scaffold(
                key: _scaffoldKey,
                appBar: AppBar(
                  elevation: 0,
                  centerTitle: true,
                  title: Text('Pick a voucher')
                ),
                body:_viewIndex==0? Column(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(),
                    RaisedButton(
                    child: Text('Next',style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white)),
                     onPressed: () {_viewIndex=1;})])),):_composeVoucherSelectionView(context,7);
          }
    
    
      Widget _composeVoucherSelectionView(BuildContext context, int rowCount) {
        if (_voucherReferenceTracker == null)
          setState(() {
            _voucherReferenceTracker = [
              for (var row
                  in List<int>.generate(rowCount, (index) => index)) // rows
                [
                  for (var side in List<int>.generate(2, (index) => index)) // sides
                    [
                      for (var voucher
                          in List<int>.generate(2, (index) => index)) // voucher
                        {
                          'state': (row == 2 && side == 1 && voucher == 1)
                              ? false
                              : null as bool
                        }
                    ] // there are two vouchers in a side, so 2 maps. true for selected, false for taken and null for empty
                ]
            ];
          });
        return Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    // child: Padding(
                    child: Card(
                        elevation: 4,
                        child: Container(
                            width: 300,
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                for (var row in List<int>.generate(
                                    rowCount, (index) => index))
                                  Row(
                                      children: [
                                        for (var side in List<int>.generate(
                                            2, (index) => index))
                                          Container(
                                              child: Row(
                                                  children: [
                                                for (var voucher in List<int>.generate(
                                                    2, (index) => index)) // 2 vouchers
                                                  FlatButton(
                                                      minWidth: 0,
                                                      onPressed:
                                                          _getOnPressedHandlerFromBooleanState(
                                                              row: row,
                                                              side: side,
                                                              voucher: voucher),
                                                      child: Image.asset(
                                                          'assets/images/voucher_${_getVoucherImageFromBooleanState(context, _voucherReferenceTracker[row][side][voucher]['state'])}.png',
                                                          width: 24,
                                                          height: 24))
                                              ],
                                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                                      MainAxisAlignment.start))
                                      ],
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween)
                              ],
                            ),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: 8, right: 8, top: 13, bottom: 3)))))
          ],
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        );
      }
    
      
      Future<bool> _onWillPop() {
        return Future(() {
          if (_viewIndex != 0) {
            setState(() {
              _viewIndex--;
            });
            return false;
          } else
            return true;
        });
      }
    
    }
```

Comment: Please post your full code because this behaviour is expected when using a unique key

Comment: Do you mean a global key? In that case I am using it in the scaffold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is that you are reassigning `_scaffoldKey` in the `build()` function. The `build()` function is ran every time that you call setState() meaning that when you are setting state you are reassigning the key and its scroll position is lost.

You should either assign the key when you define it or within the `initState()` inherited method. For your arguments, I have moved this to within the `initState()` function as you need access to `context`.

I've altered your code so that the key is assigned when you declare it and arguments are assigned within `initState()`, this will fix your issue:

```
class SearchPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _SearchPageState();
}

class _SearchPageState extends State<SearchPage> {
  Map<String, dynamic> _arguments;
  List<List<List<Map<String, bool>>>> _voucherReferenceTracker;
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  Map<String, dynamic> _selectedOffer;
  List<List<List<Map<String, bool>>>> _voucherReferenceTracker;
  var _selectedVouchers;
  var _viewIndex=0;

  @override
  void initState () {
    super.initState();
    _arguments = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: _onWillPop,
        child: Scaffold(
            key: _scaffoldKey,
            appBar: AppBar(
              elevation: 0,
              centerTitle: true,
              title: Text('Pick a voucher')
            ),
            body:_viewIndex==0? Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(),
                RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Next',style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white)),
                 onPressed: () {_viewIndex=1;})])),):_composeVoucherSelectionView(context,7);
      }


  Widget _composeVoucherSelectionView(BuildContext context, int rowCount) {
    if (_voucherReferenceTracker == null)
      setState(() {
        _voucherReferenceTracker = [
          for (var row
              in List<int>.generate(rowCount, (index) => index)) // rows
            [
              for (var side in List<int>.generate(2, (index) => index)) // sides
                [
                  for (var voucher
                      in List<int>.generate(2, (index) => index)) // voucher
                    {
                      'state': (row == 2 && side == 1 && voucher == 1)
                          ? false
                          : null as bool
                    }
                ] // there are two vouchers in a side, so 2 maps. true for selected, false for taken and null for empty
            ]
        ];
      });
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                // child: Padding(
                child: Card(
                    elevation: 4,
                    child: Container(
                        width: 300,
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            for (var row in List<int>.generate(
                                rowCount, (index) => index))
                              Row(
                                  children: [
                                    for (var side in List<int>.generate(
                                        2, (index) => index))
                                      Container(
                                          child: Row(
                                              children: [
                                            for (var voucher in List<int>.generate(
                                                2, (index) => index)) // 2 vouchers
                                              FlatButton(
                                                  minWidth: 0,
                                                  onPressed:
                                                      _getOnPressedHandlerFromBooleanState(
                                                          row: row,
                                                          side: side,
                                                          voucher: voucher),
                                                  child: Image.asset(
                                                      'assets/images/voucher_${_getVoucherImageFromBooleanState(context, _voucherReferenceTracker[row][side][voucher]['state'])}.png',
                                                      width: 24,
                                                      height: 24))
                                          ],
                                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                                  MainAxisAlignment.start))
                                  ],
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween)
                          ],
                        ),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 8, right: 8, top: 13, bottom: 3)))))
      ],
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    );
  }

  
  Future<bool> _onWillPop() {
    return Future(() {
      if (_viewIndex != 0) {
        setState(() {
          _viewIndex--;
        });
        return false;
      } else
        return true;
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: I see where I went wrong. The code works and I am now able to see that the SingleChildScrollView maintains the scroll position. Thanks a lot!