# How to maintain scroll position of screen when calling setState in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

When calling setState(), scroll position of screen is changed.
It happens in listview or screen with scroll.

- [Maintain scroll position in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70602576/how-to-save-scroll-position-of-listview-while-doing-setstate-in-flutter)
- [Maintain scroll position in SingleChildScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66092515/how-can-i-maintain-the-position-of-a-widget-in-a-singlechildscrollview-after-set)

Any other solutions?

Comment: In most cases it is maintained by default, if in your case it isn't, post your code then

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @pskink that in most cases, the scroll position is automatically maintained by default. Please check the example below, where the scroll position is automatically handled. If this behavior isn't happening in your case, please provide your code, and we'll be happy to assist you further.

```
build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Scroll Example'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 100,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text('Item $index'),
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          // Simulate setState() call
          setState(() {
            text = "11";
          });
          print("We updated text :: $text");
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
```